Selenium: Unknown error when connected by RDP
I'm running a Debian VM through Windows Hyper-V, and I connect to the system using Remote Desktop from the Windows device. This has been working amazingly for everything, except running Cucumber tests with Firefox.
Note: I can make all the tests work and pass when I run Firefox in headless mode
What I am trying to achieve is to simply run the Cucumber test, and see Firefox open and perform the required steps. Opening Firefox manually while connected with the RDP works and I can browse just fine, but when Selenium (running on the Linux machine in my RDP session) tries it, it fails:
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
/home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.6@pro/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.23.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:62:in `add_cause'
/home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.6@pro/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.23.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:41:in `error'
/home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.6@pro/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.23.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
/home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.6@pro/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.23.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
/home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.6@pro/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.23.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:101:in `new'
/home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.6@pro/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.23.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:101:in `create_response'
/home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.6@pro/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.23.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:103:in `request'
/home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.6@pro/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.23.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:67:in `call'
/home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.6@pro/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.23.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:675:in `execute'
/home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.6@pro/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.23.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:76:in `create_session'
/home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.6@pro/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.23.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:323:in `block in create_bridge'

I am trying to understand the reasoning here, because Firefox can clearly run just fine inside the RDP and render all pages, so what is missing here for the GeckoDriver to work with Firefox when invoked on an RDP?
Connection Clarification

When I connect to the Debian VM using the Connect... option from Hyper-V, I am able to run Firefox in normal mode with Selenium
When I connect to the Debian VM using Windows Remote Desktop I am not able to run Firefox in normal mode with Selenium

It is the second point I am trying to solve.
